# Excel Condition Statement IF/OR/AND

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to create a formula that will return a value of 1, 2, or 3, if a set of conditions are met. Specifically:

If `A1 = Yes`, and `B1 = Yes`, return `C1`; If `A1 = Yes`, and `B1 = No`, return `C2`; If `A1 = No`, and `B1 = No`, return `C3`

Values in `C1`, `C2`, and `C3` are set, so can be designed as a table.

I can get this to work in one row, but cannot continue the formula down, so I'm thinking my formula is flawed somewhere.

Relatievly new to formula building in Excel, but I'm pretty sure that what I want to do is possible.

Can anyone help? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: can you post the exact formula as you have it written? I suspect you may be locking cells and thus when you drag your formula down, it's not working like you want.

Answer (score 1):

For fixing locations, the `$` sign is what you need.

> =IF(AND(A1="Yes",B1="Yes"),$C$1,IF(AND(A1="Yes",B1="No"),$C$2,IF(AND(A1="No",B1="No"),$C$3,"How did you get this result")))

The `$` sign tells excel not to change that part of the reference when copying the formula, so that (in this case) the C1,C2 and C3 references will not change.